# Inequalities for f(x) is always positive

Tags: inequality

Given that $f(x)=4x^2-1$

Find the range of values of $x$ so that $f(x)$ is always positive.

My attempt,

$4x^2-1>0$

$4x^2>1$

$x^2>\frac{1}{4}$

$x>\pm\frac{1}{2}$

So $x<-\frac{1}{2}$ or $x>\frac{1}{2}$

Am I correct ?

Comment: The line $x > \pm\frac{1}{2}$ confuses me. Probably better $|x| > \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: You are absolutely right

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed you are correct.

Here is another solution just for confirmation:

$4x^2 -1 = (2x-1)(2x+1) > 0$

(1) This occurs when both are positive:

$ 2x -1 >0$ when $x > 1/2$

$ 2x +1 >0$ when $x > -1/2$

Therefore, the solution here is $x > 1/2$

(2) This also occurs when both are negative:

$ 2x -1 <0$ when $x < 1/2$

$ 2x +1 <0$ when $x < -1/2$

Therefore, the solution here is $x < -1/2$

Giving your solution set of $ x< -1/2$ 
or $ x > 1/2$

Your method, however, is indeed the preferred one. 
Another option to consider is to find the roots quickly as $1/2$ and $-1/2$, realize the function opens upwards, and quickly come to the same conclusion as previously defined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. In cases such as these, where it is very easy to sketch the (quadratic) function, you are encouraged to do so, marking the roots.

[image]

From there, you can easily see that your quadratic is positive after your positive root, and negative before your negative root. So $x > \frac{1}{2}$ and $x < -\frac{1}{2}$ is the desired solution.

---

**Note:** the quadratic is u-shaped because the coefficient of the $x^2$ term is positive. Can you solve the same variant of this problem with the sketch for $f(x) = -4x^2 + 1$? Hint: It's not u-shaped anymore.